# binutils cross-compile error

Tags: cygwin, binutils, cross-compiling

I install cygwin-x86: source/binary binutils, flex, bison, source/binary gcc, etc..
In order to cross-compile binutils, I run the follwing commands:

```
export PREFIX=/usr/cross
export TARGET=x86_64-pc-linux
cd /usr/src/binutils-2.23.51-1
./configure --target=$TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX --enable-64-bit-bfd --disable-shared --disable-nls
make configure-host
make LDFLAGS="-all-static"
make install
```

On "`make install`", It occur errors

```
./c-arc.texi:223: command @bullet not accepting argument in brace should not be on @table line
./c-arm.texi:393: command @bullet not accepting argument in brace should not be on @table line
./c-arm.texi:394: warning: @item missing argument
./c-arm.texi:397: warning: @item missing argument
./c-arm.texi:402: warning: @item missing argument
./c-arm.texi:407: warning: @item missing argument
./c-arm.texi:412: warning: @item missing argument
./c-arm.texi:415: warning: @item missing argument
./c-cr16.texi:49: warning: @item missing argument
./c-cr16.texi:51: warning: @item missing argument
./c-cr16.texi:53: warning: @item missing argument
./c-cr16.texi:58: warning: @item missing argument
./c-cr16.texi:63: warning: @item missing argument
./c-cr16.texi:65: warning: @item missing argument
./c-tic54x.texi:113: @code expected braces
./c-tic54x.texi:130: @code expected braces
./c-tic54x.texi:137: @code expected braces
./c-tic54x.texi:313: @code expected braces
as.texinfo:4385: warning: node `Byte' is next for `Bundle directives' in menu but not in sectioning
as.texinfo:4441: warning: node `Bundle directives' is prev for `Byte' in menu but not in sectioning
as.texinfo:4449: warning: node `Comm' is next for `CFI directives' in menu but not in sectioning
as.texinfo:4571: warning: node `CFI directives' is prev for `Comm' in menu but not in sectioning
./c-arm.texi:447: warning: node next `ARM-Regs' in menu `ARM-Relocations' and in sectioning `ARM-Neon-Alignment' differ
./c-arm.texi:454: warning: node prev `ARM-Neon-Alignment' in menu `ARM-Relocations' and in sectioning `ARM-Regs' differ
./c-arm.texi:476: warning: node `ARM-Neon-Alignment' is next for `ARM-Relocations' in menu but not in sectioning
./c-arm.texi:476: warning: node `ARM-Regs' is prev for `ARM-Relocations' in menu but not in sectioning
./c-arm.texi:476: warning: node up `ARM-Relocations' in menu `ARM Syntax' and in sectioning `ARM Floating Point' differ
./c-arm.texi:469: node `ARM Floating Point' lacks menu item for `ARM-Relocations' despite being its Up target
./c-i386.texi:412: warning: node `i386-Regs' is next for `i386-Mnemonics' in menu but not in sectioning
./c-i386.texi:512: warning: node `i386-Mnemonics' is prev for `i386-Regs' in menu but not in sectioning
./c-i386.texi:927: warning: node next `i386-16bit' in menu `i386-Arch' and in sectioning `i386-Bugs' differ
./c-i386.texi:979: warning: node next `i386-Bugs' in menu `i386-Notes' and in sectioning `i386-Arch' differ
./c-i386.texi:979: warning: node prev `i386-Bugs' in menu `i386-Arch' and in sectioning `i386-16bit' differ
./c-i386.texi:1000: warning: node next `i386-Arch' in menu `i386-Bugs' and in sectioning `i386-Notes' differ
./c-i386.texi:1000: warning: node prev `i386-Arch' in menu `i386-16bit' and in sectioning `i386-Bugs' differ
./c-i386.texi:1067: warning: node prev `i386-Notes' in menu `i386-Bugs' and in sectioning `i386-Arch' differ
./c-mips.texi:449: warning: node next `MIPS Stabs' in menu `MIPS ISA' and in sectioning `MIPS symbol sizes' differ
./c-mips.texi:463: warning: node next `MIPS symbol sizes' in menu `MIPS autoextend' and in sectioning `MIPS ISA' differ
./c-mips.texi:463: warning: node prev `MIPS symbol sizes' in menu `MIPS ISA' and in sectioning `MIPS Stabs' differ
./c-mips.texi:518: warning: node next `MIPS ISA' in menu `MIPS symbol sizes' and in sectioning `MIPS autoextend' differ
./c-mips.texi:518: warning: node prev `MIPS ISA' in menu `MIPS Stabs' and in sectioning `MIPS symbol sizes' differ
./c-mips.texi:557: warning: node prev `MIPS autoextend' in menu `MIPS symbol sizes' and in sectioning `MIPS ISA' differ
./c-ns32k.texi:35: warning: node next `NS32K-Dependent' in menu `SH-Dependent' and in sectioning `PDP-11-Dependent' differ
./c-pdp11.texi:6: warning: node prev `PDP-11-Dependent' in menu `SH64-Dependent' and in sectioning `NS32K-Dependent' differ
./c-score.texi:7: warning: node next `SCORE-Dependent' in menu `Sparc-Dependent' and in sectioning `SH-Dependent' differ
./c-sh.texi:6: warning: node prev `SH-Dependent' in menu `NS32K-Dependent' and in sectioning `SCORE-Dependent' differ
./c-sh64.texi:5: warning: node next `SH64-Dependent' in menu `PDP-11-Dependent' and in sectioning `Sparc-Dependent' differ
./c-sparc.texi:8: warning: node prev `Sparc-Dependent' in menu `SCORE-Dependent' and in sectioning `SH64-Dependent' differ
./c-tilepro.texi:7: warning: node next `TILEPro-Dependent' in menu `V850-Dependent' and in sectioning `Z80-Dependent' differ
./c-z80.texi:7: warning: node prev `Z80-Dependent' in menu `Xtensa-Dependent' and in sectioning `TILEPro-Dependent' differ
./c-vax.texi:7: warning: node `V850-Dependent' is next for `Vax-Dependent' in sectioning but not in menu
./c-v850.texi:5: warning: node prev `V850-Dependent' in menu `TILEPro-Dependent' and in sectioning `Vax-Dependent' differ
./c-xtensa.texi:9: warning: node `Z80-Dependent' is next for `Xtensa-Dependent' in menu but not in sectioning
Makefile:397: recipe for target 'as.info' failed
make[4]: *** [as.info] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/binutils-2.23.51-1/gas/doc'
Makefile:592: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/binutils-2.23.51-1/gas/doc'
Makefile:2182: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/binutils-2.23.51-1/gas'
Makefile:4762: recipe for target 'install-gas' failed
make[1]: *** [install-gas] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/binutils-2.23.51-1'
Makefile:2142: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

It worked well when I did cross-compile before.. so I don't know what's wrong more
What should I do?

Comment: Those are all errors from "makeinfo".  Possibly your version is too old?  Or even, maybe, too new -- I think not everybody has caught up to texinfo 4.0 yet.

Comment: @TomTromey Oh, You're right. I remove binutils from cygwin installer (version 2.23.51-xxx) and download from ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils (version 2.23.2), and It works well